# Print top output only once on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, top

On Linux, the `top` command has a "batch mode": `top -b -n 1` to print the output a set number of times. On Mac, it seems that the `top` command does not have batch mode (certainly the `-b` option does not exist).

How can I emulate `top -b -n 1` on a Mac?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's *logging mode*, with an argument specifying how often output will be repeated, `0` being until aborted. To print once and exit:

```
$ top -l 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
top -l3 -n30 > test ; tail -n42 ./test > ./test2 ; open ./test2
```

You need to repeat at least three times to have the correct CPU statistics, which is done by the option `-l3`.

I keep the 30 most important jobs, which I extract from the log file with `tail`.

`top -l` alone does not do the job for me.